# Difference in JComboBox and JSpinner

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, jspinner

I'm writing a Java Desktop utility in Java swing and have a minimal GUI part in it, most of work is done on server side i.e. backend. So, I don't want to spend a lot of time on GUI part, learning different controls and widgets. The problem is that Swing has two controls for (to me)same  tasks i.e. dropdown menu and they are `JComboBox` and `JSpinner` I don't know the difference and I don't want any limitation that would hinder me from completing my task after I've selected one.

I've to use dropdown to display `List<String>` returned from DataBase and it can have as many as thousands of values. To keep user from scrolling I'll be taking starting alphabet as input or some category limitation will be there so, it may be that I'll be using specific values to be displayed from `List<String>`. i want my program to be as efficient as it can be and spend least time on front end as there are a lot of operations on backend.

Any Help will be highly appreciated

Comment: From the JSpinner tag wiki: " Although combo boxes provide similar functionality, spinners are sometimes preferred because they don't require a drop down list that can obscure important data."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- you issue talking about [AutoComplete JComboBox / JTextField](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:714968%20autocomplete)
- with some effort could be aplied (`AutoComplete JTextField`) to `JSpinner` too

> I've to use dropdown to display List returned from DataBase and it can have as many as thousands of values.

- all above mentioned `JComponents` are based on premature array, maybe need to convert `java.util.List` to `String[]` or `Vector` (depends of your code logics)
- none of GUI are designated to helt the thousands of values, have look at `Paginations for Databases engine`
- above mentioned `AutoComplete JComboBox / JTextField` works without any issue up-to 2k rows on todays PCs
- for searching or selections from largiest arrays you have look at `Stepped JComboBox` (about two or more `JComboBoxes`)

  1.st for reduced selection from `[0-9, A-Z]`

  2.nd for searching in records started `with A` (for example)
- redirect `Database` events to the background tasks and to use `SwingWorker` or `Runnable#Thread`

Answer (score 4):

The key difference lies in the model: a [`SpinnerModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerModel.html) implementation creates a *sequence* of values, while a [`ComboBoxModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ComboBoxModel.html) does not. If objects in a `SpinnerModel` do not have a suitable natural order, you'll need to impose one.

As practical matter, "thousands of values" will benefit from an auxiliary approach, as suggested in @mKorbel's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12352869/230513).

Answer (score 2):

`JComboBox` suits your requirement. `JComboBox` is suitable for displaying a list of values. JSpinner is used when you want to do some functionality like incerement/decrement on the Spinner's text field.

This [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) explains about `JSpinner` and its similarities to `JComboBox`. There is a demo app also.